# How do I check if an object has a key in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object

Which is the right thing to do?

```
if (myObj['key'] == undefined)
```

or

```
if (myObj['key'] == null)
```

or

```
if (myObj['key'])
```

Comment: Relevant benchmarks: https://jsperf.com/checking-if-a-key-exists-in-a-javascript-array

Comment: You can try `!!myObj.key` which returns `true` (if in) and `false` (if not).

Comment: @Anh-ThiDINH be careful, this doesn't work with boolean values.


`const user = { name: "John", admin: false };
!!user.name` will return true. 
But `!!user.admin` will return false even though the 'admin' key exists

Comment: now best would be myObj?.key

Comment: I'm vote #1700 on your duplicate question :) Well done.

Answer (score 3384, accepted):

Try the [JavaScript **in** operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).

```
if ('key' in myObj)
```

And the inverse.

```
if (!('key' in myObj))
```

**Be careful!** The `in` operator matches all object keys, including those in the object's prototype chain.

Use `myObj.hasOwnProperty('key')` to check an object's own keys and will only return `true` if `key` is available on `myObj` directly:

```
myObj.hasOwnProperty('key')
```

Unless you have a specific reason to use the `in` operator, using `myObj.hasOwnProperty('key')` produces the result most code is looking for.

Comment: The reason 'in' is considered not good is because it searches the whole prototype chain.

Comment: and even better - if(myObj && 'key' in myObj)

Comment: what is wrong with searching the whole prototype chain (unless you know you don't want to for some reason)?

Comment: @reconbot, in normal OO languages you often invoke methods defined in parent classes. What is wrong doing the same thing in js? Does it imply js prototype chains themselves are bad? Some people might actually use them.

Comment: could have done like this Object.keys(ObjectInWhichYouwantTocheckTheKey).includes('keyInObject')   :)  cheers

Comment: TypeScript doesn't seem to consider `hasOwnProperty` or `in` as a type guard.

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: right-hand side of 'in' should be an object, got undefined

Comment: Should probably avoid using `hasOwnProperty` and do `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(myObj, "key");`

what if your object has actual property called `hasOwnProperty` or worse, if client adds that property in?  

Here is more context: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-prototype-builtins

Comment: @Nishant - Is the concern performance? Because otherwise it seems like checking the whole prototype chain would be desirable... you're doing this check because you want to know whether it exists before you try accessing it, presumably, and accessing it will go through the whole prototype chain if necessary...

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare, yeah performance is the concern. I haven't done (heavy) OOPS in JS, so would like to hear from experts on that. I agree it might be useful depending on the use case though :-)

Comment: @jononomo & others: It's a problem if you're using the object as a Map. If you e.g. want to make sure that an element is only once written and newer overwritten, and use `in`, you won't be able to store keys that are equal to the name of a prototype method.

Comment: @Polv TypeScript actually does consider `in` as a typeguard https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing

Comment: @DLight just checked, and `in` operator narrowing doesn't work as a typeguard in TypeScript 4.8.4. At least it's the case with how VS Code handles it and `jsconfig.json` given. Example: `if ("assignedSlot" in node) slotsSet.add(node.assignedSlot)` - yells at `node.assignedSlot` about `assignedSlot` not being in `Node` type. It stops erring when I do explicit type check via `node instanceof Element`.

Comment: @vintprox Indeed it is strange, but seems to work in TypeScript 4.9.3: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwPICMBWMC8MDeMAWApgDbEgBcMA5AO4gBOxAJlTAL4BQHA9NzIfXoNKABSEAHAVATUA1oQSsmIQhBhgQsQgA8AltBjgY0ydTxFSFGNHq6wAcwDc7KgDoOoSCGKFXZewAUiKhorvIIAJRcugBmMAFU4ax28MjoEbgcMNkwvPyCDDApACyuAByuxTAoAK6wGvlC9EVgMKUAnK4AzFk5nhDevv5BaaHhUZxAA)

Answer (score 872):

You should use [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty). For example:

```
myObj.hasOwnProperty('myKey');
```

**Note:** If you are using ESLint, the above may give you an error for violating the [no-prototype-builtins](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-prototype-builtins) rule, in that case the workaround is as below:

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(myObj, 'myKey');
```

Comment: one problem i found with hasOwnProperty in firefox is it will return false for inherited key

Comment: @maldy: isn't that the whole point of `has**Own**Property` ?

Comment: for inherited key, u can check like this if(myObj.key.key) it will return true if it exists

Comment: ESLint rejects this as `Do not access Object.prototype method 'hasOwnProperty' from target object.`

Comment: @CJBrew it might be because you have the eslint flag [no-prototype-builtins](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-prototype-builtins) in which case you can still use it by doing `{}.hasOwnProperty.call(object, "key")`

Comment: The idea of that is that if you do `myObj.hasOwnProperty()`, you are allowing myObj to intercept this call (and thus maybe mess up your logic)... However it could also be seen as an advantage that myObj can choose to do this. I personally find ESLint to be pretty anal retentive in these matters.

Comment: Worth noting that if `myObj.myKey` has actually been declared as `undefined` (for some mad reason), then `myObj.hasOwnProperty('myKey')` will return `true`.

Comment: I'm gonna leaves this here for anyone that will wonder why ESLint is complaining https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-prototype-builtins

Comment: that's an antipattern imo, **own** property should just be used for that level.

Comment: what is the key we are checking has value 0 not working for that