# how to check if an array is present or not in a json in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following JSON which I get as response:

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 1
    },
    "spellcheck": {
        "suggestions": [
            "goo",
            {
                "numFound": 4,
                "startOffset": 0,
                "endOffset": 3,
                "suggestion": [
                    "good",
                    "google",
                    "google's",
                    "goodbye"
                ]
            },
            "collation",
            "good"
        ]
    }
}
```

Now based on queries, I may get this JSON sometimes:

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 1
    }
}
```

I want to check in my jQuery code when 'spellcheck' is not present. Because otherwise it raises an exception and script stops to execute.

I have tried this:

```
if(typeof(response.spellcheck)!=='undefined')
```

but it throws exception.

Help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i check if an object has a key in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455338/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-key-in-javascript)

Comment: `typeof` works as: `typeof response.spellcheck !== 'undefined'`. But you should use `hasOwnProperty` anyway.

Comment: @adrianp: That question is not answered properly. Have you read the answer(s) to that question before down-voting my question? Spend some time to read answers also :P. Read the comment in accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just say `if(response && response.spellcheck)` ...

Comment: is your `response` object null? can you alert that and see?

Comment: what exception do you get ?

Comment: It is solved thanks. Actually I need to check: if(response.spellcheck.suggestions[1]){} too.

Comment: Please use `hasOwnProperty` to check the existence of object attributes.

Comment: This is what I get if I use hasOwnProperty: "ReferenceError: spellcheck is not defined"

Comment: @stalin You get that because you do `hasOwnProperty(spellcheck)` when you should actually use `hasOwnProperty('spellcheck')`. Maybe you should go over the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

Answer (score 1):

Try `hasOwnProperty`:

```
if(response.hasOwnProperty("spellcheck")) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: do I have any try catch method for this?

Comment: Defining "does not work" for you: "ReferenceError: spellcheck is not defined"

Comment: @stalin This means that you're still checking for _spellcheck_ as a property.  Note that in this case it must be in quotes - a string.

Answer (score 0):

try `if (response && response.hasOwnProperty('spellcheck') && response.spellcheck) {/*your code here*/}`

Answer (score -1):

assign your json to a variable say response and check for it length

```
if ( response['spellcheck'].length < 1 ) {
// it's empty
}
```