# Equivalent of Python's KeyError exception in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to access a certain member in a JavaScript object. In order to do this, I need to try out a couple of key values.

For example, `Object['text/html']` which will give me an export link for a HTML document. However, not every object of this type will have a `text/html` key pair value.

In Python I would solve this problem using a Try-Catch block, with the `KeyError` exception. If I can do something similar in javascript, as in use an exception in a Try-Catch block, that would be great.

However, if alternatives exists instead of try catch blocks, that do achieve the same end goal, I would like to know about them as well.

## EDIT:

I would prefer to use an exception over using functions. I do this because the `text/html` key might not be there, but it *should* be there. An exception seems more appropriate for this scenario

Comment: Missing keys return `undefined` in js, no errors are raised.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1098955/846892

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if an associative array key exists in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-an-associative-array-key-exists-in-javascript)

Comment: @Pointy Well that gives a way to do things, but is there an exception I could use?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac I don't think javascript likes [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) approach, so why do you want an exception?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac no; referencing a non-existent property is not an error in JavaScript. It's just an expression that evaluates to `undefined`.

Comment: @hcwhsa Primarily because it _is_ an exception. The key is _supposed_ to be there, but it is not. This might very well happen, however. Thus, I believe that it is more appropriate to use an exception in this case.

Comment: See my answer.  JS doesn't generate exceptions when reading or writing a property that doesn't exist.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac But that's not an exception in js, you shouldn't write python code in js. Go for [LBYL](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Javascript doesn't generate an exception when reading or writing a property that doesn't exist.  When reading it, it just returns `undefined`.  When writing it, it just creates the property.

You could create your own function that tests to see if the property exists and throws an exception if it does not (but you'd have to call that function whenever), but JS doesn't make an exception out of that on it's own like you are asking for.

---

If you want to test if a key exists on an object in javascript, you can use this construct with the `in` operator:

```
var obj = {};
var key = "test";

if (key in obj) {
    // key exists
} else {
    // key doesn't exist
}
```

---

If you try to read a key that doesn't exist, you will get `undefined` as the value.

```
var obj = {};
var value = obj.test;

alert(value === undefined);
```

The `in` operator does a better job of telling you whether the key exists that testing for `undefined` because `undefined` is a legal value for a key that exists.

---

In many cases, where you control the values that the keys have and a key that is present will never have a falsey value, you can also just check if the key has a truthy value:

```
var obj = {};
var obj.test = "hello";

if (obj.test) {
    // key exists and has a truthy value
}
```

---

If you want to make sure that the object itself has the property and not any prototype that it is inheriting from, then you can do this:

```
var obj = {};
var obj.test = "hello";

if (obj.hasOwnProperty(test)) {
    // key exists on the object itself (not only on the prototype)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the reason why exceptions cannot be used. I hope I could convey _why_ I needed one. Also, thanks for this answer, its more than suffice for my uses.

Comment: 7 years later...probably solved it by this point...but I will add that `myObj.noKeyHere.noKeyHereEither` will result in a `TypeError`

Answer (score 0):

#### Read this!

The accepted answer **is correct** however omits some points.

#### 1) Accessing nested object

Like someone pointed out in the comment, Javascript returns `undefined` when the key doesn't exists in the object.

However, if you need to access an object inside an object (or an Array, or a function), well this break.

```
let a = {};
let userName = 'js'
let data = a.response[userName];
```

Cuz you will received actually a `TypeError`, basically because we are trying to read a property of undefined, which doesn't have any.

```
VM187:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'js')
    at <anonymous>:2:22
```

#### 2 Answering the question

The Python principle ["Ask forgiveness not permission" - explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain) is actually for the most part working well in Javascript (and PHP, you didn't ask but well..). There are for sure some difference, or some situation where the difference is important, but **for most use cases is the same**

So this is how you would do it:

```
try {
    let data = a.key1.key2['whatever'].nested.damn.object;
    console.log(data)
} catch (error) {
    let data = "noope"; 
    console.log(data);

}
```

As you can see, in Javascript you don't really care about the error type, (for the most part, sure other situation you should case). Is almost like anything is in a Python's

```
try:
   a = "hello" + 1 + {} + [] # crazy stuff here
except BaseException as bleh:
   print(str(bleh))
```

#### Documentatin

- [MDN Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#objects_and_properties)
- [How do I check if an object has a key in JavaScript? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/455338/13903942)