# check param in object in ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I have list with some persons, and if this person have comment field - you can edit this information in `input:text`. So I show this field when person have this field. But I have a problem, when I remove previous comment - input is hide. It's couse `person.comment = ""`, and I think it meens like false.

```
<input person="text" ng-show='person.comment' ng-model='person.comment'>
```

i try to do this thing:

```
ng-show='person.comment || person.comment === ""'
```

but perhaps exist a different way? like `comment in person`? [My plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BTbeIaaR8cx9cXXfCToB?p=preview).

Comment: looks like your attempt does solve the problem if I understand this correctly. In the plunker, if I add `ng-show='person.comment || person.comment === ""'` the input field does not disappear on a deletion of the text in the input field.

Comment: @Matthias yes it is, but sometimes (not often) person.comment - undefined, so I need to make `ng-show='person.comment || person.comment === ""' || person.comment === undefined` and this looks ugly, so perhaps we have a better way to check. like we do in `if` `if(comment in person)` for example

Comment: in what situation do you actually want to hide the input field? could use that, and show it in all other cases

Comment: @Matthias I use it in plnkr, Jake and Jane has no fields, couse they has no param comment in they object

Comment: in that case, `comment in person` should indeed be what you want.

Comment: @Matthias but It's not working in ng-model..

Comment: did you add the quotes? `ng-show="'comment' in person"` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455338/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-key-in-javascript

Comment: or better might be `person.hasOwnProperty('comment')`

Comment: @Matthias yes I miss quotes) but hasOwnPropety - is better way! you can write your answer and I will vote) thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if an object has a key in javascript, for you, you could write:

`ng-show="person.hasOwnProperty('comment')"`

from [How do I check if an object has a key in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455338/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-key-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Add Simply angular.forEach loop on $scope.stuff array Like:-

**Js**

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.hideVariable = true;
    $scope.stuff = [
      {
       name: 'Jack',
       age : 22,
       comment : 'good boy'
      },
      {
       name: 'Bob',
       age : 23,
       comment : 'likes beer'
      },
      {
       name: 'Alisa',
       age : 21,
       comment : 'pretty girl'
      },
      {
       name: 'Jane',
       age : 25,
       comment : "she's fine"
      },
      {
       name: 'Mike',
       age : 19,
       comment : 'playing guitar'
      }
    ]
   angular.forEach('$scope.stuff', function (data) {
      if(data.comment === null || data.comment === 'undefined' ) {
        $scope.hideVariable = false;
      }
   })
})
```

**HTML**

```
<input person="text"ng-show="hideVariable" ng-model='person.comment'>
```

**Go through this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/O8WAU1ti2uuffDcliP1p?p=preview)**

Comment: nope, without ng-show persons without `comment` will be have input too

Comment: Ok then simply add for loop in your Js and pass one boolean variable to make your field enable disable, wait I ll update the answer