# How do I get the value of a key from a list of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a list of objects in the following way:

```
obj = [ { a:[1,2,3] }, { b:[4,5,6] }, { c:[7,8,9] } ]
```

How do I get the correspoding array for a key using javascript?

Eg. For b, I would get [4,5,6]. I need a function where I can give the key as input and it returns me the corresponding array associated with it.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: This is a strange and somewhat inconvenient data structure.  Is there a reason you're using an array of separate objects each with a unique key name, instead of just a single object like `obj = {a: [1,2,3], b: [4,5,6], c: [7,8,9]}`?

Comment: Actually this is a return I get from an api call and the data comes in this format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: @str Not exactly the same question that

Comment: No not exactly the same, but close enough to qualify as a duplicate. And I'm sure if you searched a little longer than I did, you would have found an exact duplicate. Some effort from your side is expected.

Comment: I could not relate it to my question. Hence I posted a question. I have been trying to get this right for a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find()` and `Object.keys()`. Compare the first element of keys array to the given key.

```js
const arr = [ { a:[1,2,3] }, { b:[4,5,6] }, { c:[7,8,9] } ];
const getByKey = (arr,key) => (arr.find(x => Object.keys(x)[0] === key) || {})[key]

console.log(getByKey(arr,'b'))
console.log(getByKey(arr,'c'))
console.log(getByKey(arr,'something'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

```js
let obj = [ { a:[1,2,3] }, { b:[4,5,6] }, { c:[7,8,9] } ]

let findByKey = (arr,key) => {
  return (arr.find(ele=> key in ele ) || {})[key]
}

console.log(findByKey(obj,'b'))
console.log(findByKey(obj,'xyz'))
```

Comment: That may cause unwanted sideeffects and false trues. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455338/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-key-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` and `hasOwnProperty`

```js
const arr = [ { a:[1,2,3] }, { b:[4,5,6] }, { c:[7,8,9] } ];

const byKey = (arr, key) => {
    return (arr.find(e => e.hasOwnProperty(key)) || {})[key];
};

console.log(byKey(arr, 'a'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use a property indexer i.e. `obj['b']`