# How to check if a key is exists in JSON Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

I am having the JSON array of objects like below,

```
   let data = [
       {
          "node":[
             {
                "name":"aaaaa",
                "count":"2",
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "client":[
             {
                "name":"bbbbb",
                "count":"2",
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "ip_address":[
             {
                "name":"ccccc",
                "count":"3",
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "compute":[
             {
                "name":"dddd",
                "count":"1",
             }
          ]
       }
    ]

let find_key = "ip_address";
```

Need to check whether the root key is exists or not(for example need to find `ip_address` is exists or not). **without foreach** please.

JSFiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/b9gxhnko/

Tried the following ways but no luck. Some help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Tried like below, but its not working (always returning `false`),

```
    console.log(data[0].has(find_key)); // false
    console.log(data.has(find_key)); // false
    console.log(data[0].hasOwnProperty(find_key)); // false
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an object has a key in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455338/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-key-in-javascript)

Comment: those are using has method, but i need with _some. I got the answer. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with [`array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
let exists = data.some(x => x[find_key]);
```

```js
  let data = [
       {
          "node":[
             {
                "name":"aaaaa",
                "count":"2",
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "client":[
             {
                "name":"bbbbb",
                "count":"2",
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "ip_address":[
             {
                "name":"ccccc",
                "count":"3",
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "compute":[
             {
                "name":"dddd",
                "count":"1",
             }
          ]
       }
    ]

let find_key = "ip_address";

let exists = data.some(x => x[find_key]);
console.log(exists);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of objects, and `_.has()` an the `in` expect as single object. Right now you check if the array has a key called `ip_address`, which it doesn't. Use `Array.some()` or lodash's `_.some()`, and check if each object has the key:

```js
const data = [{"node":[{"name":"aaaaa","count":"2"}]},{"client":[{"name":"bbbbb","count":"2"}]},{"ip_address":[{"name":"ccccc","count":"3"}]},{"compute":[{"name":"dddd","count":"1"}]}]

// vanilla JS
const result1 = data.some(o => 'ip_address' in o)

console.log(result1)

// lodash
const result2 = _.some(data, o => _.has(o, 'ip_address'))

console.log(result1)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```