# Single line subobject check

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm working with two objects in JS and I need to know if a given subobject exists. My objects look something like this:

```
obj1 = {
   sobj1: 1234,
   sobj2: {
      ssobj1: "abc",
      ssobj2: 1234
   }
}
```

The catch is that I don't know beforehand the exact shape of the object and when I try to check if `ssojb1` exists with an `if (obj1.sobj2.ssobj1)` and `sobj2` isn't set, I'll get an error like "trying to read property `ssobj1` of `undefined`.

To circumvent this, my approach was to use a cascade of `if` statements, but I'm pretty sure that there's a better option. This can get ugly pretty quickly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an object has a key in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455338/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-key-in-javascript)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining, not sure if widely supported yet. Lodash also has a `get` where you can specify a path and a default value https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get

Comment: @mousetail yes it does! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to mousetail for the solution.

Appearently using `if ('key' in obj)` does the trick, even if obj is undefined.

So:

```
if ('ssobj1' in obj1) {   // true or false
   do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator supported in modern browsers `?.`, but you may still be working with `if` statements at that point. In these cases, utilities may help you.

```js
const isDefined = x => typeof x !== 'undefined'

const { get } = rubico

const pathsToCheck = [
  'sobj2.ssobj1',
  'sobj2.ssobj3',
]

const checkPath = (path, obj) => isDefined(get(path)(obj))

const obj1 = {
   sobj1: 1234,
   sobj2: {
      ssobj1: "abc",
      ssobj2: 1234
   }
}

for (const path of pathsToCheck) {
  console.log(path, checkPath(path, obj1))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rubico"></script>
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of rubico.

[Documentation for get](https://doc.rubico.land/#get)

Comment: Thanks, but that makes the code longer than my current solution.