# Dictionary .has("key") not working, must use dictionary["key"] != "undefined" instead

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dictionary

(Using javascript)

I've seen some answers saying `dictionary.has("key")` will evaluate to `true` or `false` based on if the key is in the dictionary. For some reason, this hasn't worked for me at all. Only `dictionary["key"] != "undefined"` works for me. Why is this?

Comment: There is no such thing as `dictionary` in JavaScript

Comment: https://pietschsoft.com/post/2015/09/05/javascript-basics-how-to-create-a-dictionary-with-keyvalue-pairs

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) - by the way, the link you supplied never uses `.has` ... so ... not sure what you actually read to think an Object has `has`

Comment: `dictionary["key"] != "undefined"` checks if `dictionary.key` is not the string `"undefined"`. Not sure why you would compare against the string. Which resource states that a `has` method exists? Which prototype does it supposedly exist on? See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/4642212) and read the docs of [`hasOwnProperty`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) and [Maps’ `has`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean `object` in JS

To evaluate if a key exists in an object:

```
if ('key' in dictionary)
```

Otherwise, to evaluate if the key does not exist

```
if (!('key' in dictionary))
```

PD: `has` is used for maps https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has

Ref: [How do I check if an object has a key in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455338/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-key-in-javascript)

Comment: @pls Please familiarize yourself with the [difference between `in` and `hasOwnProperty`](/q/13632999/4642212).