# Write a function that takes a user object and returns the value of the password key

Tags: javascript, function, javascript-objects

New learner here, I'm stuck on a practice question for a course and I'm not sure what it's asking me to do here. The problem is as follows:

> Write a function that takes a user object, which represents a user of
> the Northcoders website, and returns the value of the password key
> from that object.
>
> If the user object does not contain a password key, the function
> should instead return undefined.
>
> A typical user object might look like this:
>
> ```
> { name: 'Lucy', password: 'n0rthc0derzzz' }
> ```
>
> Requirements are as follows:
>
> - Returns undefined when given a user
>   object where no password key is present - check
> - Returns a password
>   from a user object when a password key is present - unchecked
>
> Starting code is:
>
> ```
> function retrievePassword (user) {
> // Your code goes here...
> ```

So judging by `//Your code goes here...` I'm not supposed to change the arguments for the function since I'm supposed to write my code below.

Any help much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out for bracket notation to access key in an object.

Comment: @HassanImam Bracket notation isn't needed, since it's not a dynamic key.

Comment: check `hasOwnProperty` documentation. or this link hat is similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455338/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-key-in-javascript

Comment: This is basic property access of an object, it should be one of the first things you learned about objects. Just use `variable.propertyname` to get it. Replace `variable` and `propertyname` with the appropriate names for your function. I can't say much more without doing your homework for you.

Comment: @MeBottleOScrumpy That's not needed. If the property doesn't exist, you'll get `undefined` when you try to read it, and that's what they're supposed to return.

Comment: See this tutorial

Comment: 0 efforts were taken before asking the question 

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this too for a while.

```
function retrievePassword (user) {
if (user.hasOwnProperty("password")){
  console.log(user.password);
  return user.password;
} else {
  return undefined;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function retrievePassword (user) {
  return user.password
}
```

or

```
function retrievePassword ({ password }) {
  return password
}
```

or

```
const retrievePassword = ({ password }) => password
```

or

```
const retrievePassword = (user) => user.password
```

Comment: Please don't do their homework for them.

Comment: On top of not doing homework, it doesn't follow the requirements for _presence_ of a key vs what the value is.

Comment: @chazsolo I don't understand what requirement. *If the user object does not contain a password key, the function should instead return undefined.* this is fulfilled