# check if property exist inside List of objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I have list of objects response.tasks:
`{userLastName: ', srCreationDate: '', idNumber: '', firstName: ', insStartDate: null, …}`
and I want to know if I have some properties
for `userLastName` it will be true
for 'example' will be false.
I need to write this condition via html

I tried `'userLastName' in response.tasks`

```
response.tasks.hasOwnProperty('userLastName')

response.tasks.includes('userLastName')`
```

but all of them were false

Comment: See if this helps- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455338/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-key-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

You have an array (multiple items) so you need to check if "some" item has the property

```
response.tasks.some(task => task.hasOwnProperty('userLastName'))
```

or "every" item has the property

```
response.tasks.every(task => task.hasOwnProperty('userLastName'))
```

depending on your requirements

Comment: Thank you so much! do you know how can I do it in html`<div *ngIf="tasks?.some(task => task.hasOwnProperty('userLastName'))" mat-sort-header="srCreationDate"></div>` because I am using `<ng-container *ngIf="(tasks$ | async) as tasks">`  to see the data

Comment: @UriPerkal This is angular not html, right? I am not an expert in angular, but it seems that something like this should do the trick. Though I suggest you to put this logic somewhere else in your component code to keep your template as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` operator.

> The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the
> specified object or its prototype chain.

Example:

```
interface I1 {
    userLastName: string
}


let myVar: I1 = {
    userLastName: 'test'
}

console.log('userLastName' in myVar); // returns true
```